# how to remove (not hiding) columns from a DevExpress gridView?

Tags: c#, gridview

I load my data into a `GridView` using `DataSet`. At first databinding, it works well. But when I run query that return different columns, the `GridView` show the new column plus the old one. I've tried the `gridView1.Columns.Clear()` method, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Here are some of the code:

```
// loading data into dataset
dataSet dsGrid = new dataSet();
string dtMember = "kpi";

// note: "thequery" is query generated based on user's selection
using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(thequery, myCn))
{
da.Fill(dsGrid, dtMember);
}

// set the gridControl's datasource
gc_report.DataSource = null;

// clear the columns
gridView1.Columns.Clear();

// bind the data
gc_report.DataSource = dsGrid;
gc_report.DataMember = dtMember;
```

When I run my application, it runs well, but if the query return different column, the old column still appear although I've put the `Clear()` method of the `gridView1.Columns` collection.

How to set the `gridView1` , so the grid always shows the current query?

Comment: your code shows `gridControl1`,`gridView1` and `gc_report` . which is the original gird?

Comment: Thanks for reply...

Oh, sorry for misunderstanding... I have edited my sample code above.

The original grid is gridView1, and the gridcontrol that own the gridView1 is gc_report.

The logic is, I set the gc_report's datasource into null, then I clear the columns in gridView1, and then rebind the gc_report's datasource.

After rebinding, the old columns still appear, although I have called the gridView1.Clear() method.

My question is, how to set the gridView1, so the grid always show new columns?

Is there any wrong code?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.